# Why are none of my actions showing up in the Action Editor?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with QT framework and have encountered a problem where none of my actions are being displayed in the Action Editor. I have many buttons and I can edit my actions in the action slots and my code so I know that I have actions in the project, but there are none in the Action Editor. This really limits what I can do since I can't find a way to add icons to my buttons without using the Action Editor. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **Qt Widgets Application**:

You have to right click on the button, press *Go to slot*, and create your **function, action, or whatever you want**.

You can use `Signals/Slots` too, when a button is clicked, send and signal to a slot (
theoretically).

Comment: I've already pressed Go to slot and written the code on all of my buttons. The problem is that on the Action Editor, none of those actions show up, so I can't add icons to my buttons, since the only way to do that is via the Action Editor. To be clear: I have already created my actions, added the code for them, and they work when I run the program. They're just not showing up in the action editor for some reason.

Comment: What you write into "go to slot" is the things that the function button clicked will do, so it's not even to appear on action editor! About icons, is there others ways to insert an icon to your button, the more easier is to create a QLabel, enable pixmap on the object, and select the image file, the next step is to line up the label to the button.